# Query to find records with more than one date

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build a query for a MS SQL database that will find records with more than one year but not the records with only one.

Lets say I have a car dealership and I have 1 Chevy from 2015 and 2 from 2017 then I would want to find Chevy 2015 1 and chevy 2017 2 but if I have a three Fords from 2018 and only 2018 then I don't want that at all.

I have tweeked with groups and joins but I don't get any where.  So I need `Select from table` something.  I'm leaning toward a pivot table but not sure what to do.  Thanks for the help

**MyTable Contents**

```
              Model  year   count
              Chevy 2012    1
              Chevy 2012    1
              Chevy 2015    1
              Ford  2018    1
              Ford  2018    1
              Ford  2018    1   
              Buick 2017    1
              Lexus 2017    1
              Lexus 2015    1
```

**Desired Result Set**

```
             Chevy  2012    2
             Chevy  2015    1
             Lexus 2017    1
             Lexus 2015    1
```

Because it has 2 different years for the model

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: You need to post actual details instead of making other guess at the details. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: A join could work..what did you try when you "tweeked with groups and joins"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query should help you. Need not hardcode model values.

```
Select T.Model,T.[year] ,count(T.[year])
from T
join (select distinct * from T) S on T.model = S.model and T.year!=S.year
group by T.Model,T.[year]
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, please upvote and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM` function and `group by` on subquery,Because there might be Multiple count on `count` column. then join itself and `distinct` to exclude duplicate data.

```
Select distinct t1.*
from (
  SELECT Model,[year] ,sum([count]) totle
  FROM T
  group by Model,[year] 
) t1
inner join T t2 on t1.Model = t2.Model and t1.[year] !=t2.[year]
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e8756/55*

Note:[table],[year] are keyword in sql avoid naming it as column name

Comment: sorry but I just update the question it can be any model, not just a Chevy.  Any model that has two different years

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the issue. You don't want to hardcode the Model values.